# Firebase with Angular: packages discrepancy

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to incorporate firebase (FireStore, Authentication, ...) into an Angular webapp. I added the latest `@angular/fire`-package to my package.json file but when compiling I get an error.

> Generic type 'AggregateQuerySnapshot' requires 1 type argument(s).

[image]

Now this error suddenly solves itselves when simply adding the package `firebase` to my dependencies. But unwilling to needlesly add dependencies, I simply changed the source code to

```
export type CountSnapshot = lite.AggregateQuerySnapshot<any>;
```

So far it compiles but now when I run the app, I get a runtime error in my `AuthenticationService`.

> error is TypeError: Class constructor BrowserPopupRedirectResolver cannot be invoked without 'new'

```
import { Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, AuthCredential, GoogleAuthProvider, browserPopupRedirectResolver, signInWithPopup, signOut, user } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { UserManagementService } from '../shared/service/user-management.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {

  private readonly googleAuthProvider: GoogleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  private readonly auth: Auth = inject(Auth);
  ...



  public async logingGoogle(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(this.auth, this.googleAuthProvider, browserPopupRedirectResolver);
      // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      if (!credential) throw Error('Credential not given');
      const token = credential.accessToken;
      // The signed-in user info.
      const user = result.user;


      this.userManagementService.userSubject.next(user);
    }
    catch (error: any) {
      console.log('error is', error);
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      // The email of the user's account used.
      const email = error.customData.email;
      // The AuthCredential type that was used.
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    }
  }
}
```

To combat this, I did really have to add the `firebase` dependency and import the `browserPopupRedirectResolver` from there.

```
// import { Auth, AuthCredential, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, signOut } from '@angular/fire/auth'; // From this
import { Auth, AuthCredential, GoogleAuthProvider, browserPopupRedirectResolver, signInWithPopup, signOut } from 'firebase/auth'; // To this
```

But now all other things break since I am workin with completely different classes etc. I can also no longer import `Auth`

[image]

So a lot of question pop up for me.

1. Why do I need two dependencies?
2. How is the overlap between the two?
3. Which one should I always use?
4. How would I need to configure the setup? I.e. in my `AppModule`

Because when using two different packages, would I need to initialize my firebase app twice? It really is unclear how Google publishes its packages and why they release packages that don't even compile in the first place. I thought it was a bug at first, but if so then it is one that is around for way too long.